# multi-label classification in python

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I am beginning to use Pybrain which good neural networks algorithms. If anybody is familiar with it already, is the package capable of doing multi-label classification as well?
Multi-label is different from multi-class classification because an instance can have more than one class as their output/target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question is a bit vague.*

## Yes

I believe I've understood you correctly, and **yes** PyBrain is capable of doing such a task. Neural networks in Pybrain are capable (through supervised learning<sup>1</sup> ) of doing instance classification through multi-labeling the input values.

#### Just a tip:

Since you are performing a logical separation of the input instances I recommend using the `sigmoid logistic function` given that your input are in the range of `[0, 1]`. If your input range is the Real Numbers, the tanh has proven a lot faster on average<sup>2</sup>

### Example outputs

```
    # The outputs are sqashed by the sigmoid( ) function

    0 1 1 0 # class one
    1 1 1 0 # class one
    0 0 1 0 # class two
    0 1 1 1 # class two
    0 0 1 0 # class three
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I've not studied unsupervised learning, so I dare not state otherwise.
<sup>2</sup> See [this](http://www.heatonresearch.com/comment/3189#comment-3189) for a quick benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if it helps, [Scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) is another package which supports multi-label classification using deep learning libraries like theano, tensorflow, keras and scikit-neuralnetworks.