# multi-label classification and stratified sampling with different preparation of target value will get different result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification, imbalanced-data

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
                                         Clean_Tweet     cEXT  cNEU cAGR  cCON  cOPN
0      thanks questions watch season premiere tonight     0     1     1     1    0
1                            couple films coming book     0     0     0     1    1
2                                  naked afford price     0     1     0     1    1
```

I want to apply multi-label classification on this data set. As my data set is imbalanced I need to use stratified sampling.

I am confused in the way I need to prepare the `y` value and pass it to the `iterative_train_test_split`.

I have done in two ways and got veryyy different results. I was wondering if you can help me understand which way is the correct way.

**First scenario:**

**1.** I transform my data set in this shape:

```
0    thanks questions watch season premiere tonight     [cNeu, cAgr, cCon]
1    couple films coming book                           [cCON, cOPN]
2    naked afford price                                 [cNeu, cCON, cOPN]
```

**2.** And then used multilabel-binarizer:

```
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df.personality)
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df.personality)
```

**3.** And then call sampling:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(np.array(df['Clean_Tweet']).reshape(-1,1), y, test_size = 0.33)
```

And then use `tfidf` vectorizer and pass to `OneVSRest linear svc` to classify (If knowing that code might help as well please let me know I will post it here)

In this way my performance of `f1, precision, recall` is around `95 percent`

**Second Scenario**

**1.** I transform my data set in this shape:

```
0    thanks questions watch season premiere tonight     [cNeu, cAgr, cCon]
1    couple films coming book                           [cCON, cOPN]
2    naked afford price                                 [cNeu, cCON, cOPN]
```

**2.** And then used multilabel-binarizer:

```
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df.personality)
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df.personality)
```

**3.** And then I apply **LabelEncoding on the binarized target**:

```
def get_new_labels(y):
    y_new = LabelEncoder().fit_transform([''.join(str(l)) for l in y])
    return y_new

y_new = get_new_labels(y)
y_new = y_new.reshape(len(y_new), 1)
```

**4.** And then:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(np.array(df['Clean_Tweet']).reshape(-1,1), y_new, test_size = 0.33)
```

With the same `tfidf` and `OneVSRest linear svc`, I got around `68 percent` performance.

My question is that which way is the correct way of doing this and why is that difference?

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813194/multi-label-image-classification) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819311/multi-label-classification-in-python) and it did not help with my question.

Comment: I am interested in the same problem. I think you understand more than me so if you don't mind I will ask you a question. Can you not supply the y value as a matrix of binary label indicators, much like the way your labels are represented in your original data before you transform to this shape '[cNeu, cAgr, cCon]'?